# Rails Form with belongs_to Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, belongs-to

I'm very new to Rails so this may be an obvious problem, and if so I apologize.

I am trying to create a form for creating a  `User` record, which has a `belongs_to` association with a `Team` model. What I've done so far is the following...

```
<% form_for @user, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>

  <% f.fields_for :team do |team| %>
    <%= team.collection_select(:team_id, Team.all, :id, :name) %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This seems to work well enough, but when creating the User record I'm running into trouble.

```
def create
  @team = Team.find(params[:user][:team][:team_id])
  @team.users.create(user_params)
  # Ignoring error checking for brevity
end

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
end
```

The params now contains a field for `team_id` which is not an attribute of the `User` model, and thus the creation fails. I'm not sure how to go about addressing that, let alone whether or not this is the appropriate way to approach this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If a user belongs_to a team it should have a team_id since belongs_to is in the side with the foreign key?  Also you don't need the fields_for  unless you where doing something with nested attributes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't entirely aware of how the belongs_to association actually works, you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

welcome to Rails :)

There is no problem with your logic of going about the association this way if the goal is to make sure that each user can be part of a team.

So first you'll need to make sure that `team_id` exists on the user model.  And seoncdly, as Doon suggested, you don't need `fields_for` unless you want to interact with the team model and make changes from within that same form.

So first create a migration
`rails g migration add_team_to_user team:belongs_to`

using belongs_to in your migration will add a reference, which you can learn about here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Then migrate your database
`bundle exec rake db:migrate`

and restart your server.  Then change your form like so:

```
<% form_for @user, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:team_id, Team.all, :id, :name) %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

easy to do this use the gem https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

**Associations**

To deal with associations, Simple Form can generate select inputs, a series of radios buttons or checkboxes. Lets see how it works: imagine you have a user model that belongs to a company and has_and_belongs_to_many roles. The structure would be something like:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Now we have the user form:

```rb
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.association :company %>
  <%= f.association :roles %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```